# How to allow new PC IP to log onto Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

**Can I put this question on hold?** I need to install an Xwindows client on the new PC first. That might be the problem. It's been years since I've done something like this.

- Client (the new PC) is Windows 10 running putty v0.73. I use ssh to log into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using Putty.
- Due to the weird configuration, and me working at home from quarantine, I only have access to the shell, not a GUI for Ubuntu.
- I've tried to connect to Ubuntu and I can enter my username and password but then nothing else happens. No error message or anything.
- I set up putty to send Xterm to the new PC's IP address, which is, let's say, 10.1.1.11.
- I also set up the DISPLAY variable in putty for the new PC, which contains 10.1.1.11. I set it up just like my old PC.
- Connecting using Putty from my old PC, with a different IP, say 10.1.1.10, works fine. Ignore the fact that these are made up IPs.
- I'm not a sysadmin and I'm all on my own for this one.
- I looked at my older questions from 2014 but all my questions from before 2016 were deleted from this site, so that's no help.

My question is, I think I have to allow this new IP on the new PC at the ubuntu level. In my `/etc/hosts.allow` file I already have `ALL:10.1.*.*` which should allow all IPs that start with 10.1, right?

Do I also have to add the new PC IP for some xterm file? I need Xwindows and nedit supported and I don't know which config files to edit.

I use ufw for the firewall, do I have to edit some config file for that too to allow the new IP through?

But it no worky. Any ideas what I should check on the ubuntu side?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Are you connecting using telnet or ssh?

Comment: Putty is set up to use SSH. Perhaps there's I have to allow the new PC IP via SSH? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing 5 projects at once and I can no longer edit my previous comment. I just want to get Xwindows working on this new PC. SSH and the terminal works if I don't use Xwindows. It's the xwindows part I'm having problems with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty